# How to handle off-topic questions when there is a more appropiate SE site

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, flagging, public-beta

When encountering an off-topic question, what are the best ways to handle it when the more appropriate site is:

1. A fully public stackexchange site (e.g. stackoverflow.com)
2. A stackexchange site in public beta
3. A stackexchange site in private beta

Answer (score 2):

As there's no migration (until this site becomes fully public) you can only vote to close as "off topic" (assuming you have enough rep) and add a comment about where it would be better asked.

This applies to the first two cases. It also applies to the third (and unstated 4th case where there's a proposed site that hasn't reached beta yet) but you need to change the wording and direct the OP to Area 51.

If you haven't got the rep to vote yet still add the comment and flag for moderator attention. We'll see the flags and then close the question (nearly) straight away if we agree with you. On a personal note if I'm not 100% certain I'll leave the question open to see if any other moderator or 500+ rep user agrees.